# How to write an RSpec for a Mail Interceptor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, email-spec

I'm using a mail interceptor as follows:

**setup_mail.rb**

```
Mail.register_interceptor(MailInterceptor) if Rails.env != "production"
```

**class MailInterceptor**

```
class MailInterceptor  
  def self.delivering_email(message)  
    message.subject = "#{message.subject} [#{message.to}]"
    message.to = "xxxxx@xxxxxx.com"
  end
end
```

I'm unable to create an rspec for this interceptor as it is not happen with rake spec.

I have the following spec:

```
  describe "MailInterceptor" do 
    it "should be intercepted" do
      @email = UserMailer.registration_automatically_generated(@user)
      @email.should deliver_to("xxxxx@xxxxxx.com")      
    end
  end
```

In the test.log I see that the deliver_to is not the interceptor. Any ideas on how I can write an rspec for the interceptor?

Thanks

Comment: does the interceptor work in dev? where is setup_mail.rb stored?

Comment: Yes it is setup in initalizers/setup_mail.rb w Mail.register_interceptor(MailInterceptor) if Rails.env != "production"

Answer (score 15):

The email_spec matcher for `deliver_to` doesn't actually run the mail message through the typical delivery methods, it [simply inspects the message](https://github.com/bmabey/email-spec/blob/master/lib/email_spec/matchers.rb#L34) for who it is being sent to.

To test your interceptor, you can invoke the delivering_email method directly

```
it 'should change email address wen interceptor is run' do
  email = UserMailer.registration_automatically_generated(@user)
  MailInterceptor.delivering_email(email)
  email.should deliver_to('xxxxx@xxxxxx.com')
end
```

The other option is to let the message deliver as normal, and test that it was sent to the right place using email_spec's `last_email_sent`

```
it 'should intercept delivery' do
  reset_mailer
  UserMailer.registration_automatically_generated(@user).deliver
  last_email_sent.should deliver_to('xxxxx@xxxxxx.com')
end
```

It might be a good idea to use both tests, the first to make sure that `MailInterceptor` is altering the message as you would expect.  The second test is more of an integration test, testing that `MailInterceptor` is hooked in to the delivery system.